# Enable MathJax in RSS feeds for Wordpress blogs

Tags: wordpress, google-reader, mathjax

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is a very nice javascript library to write LaTeX code within an html file. I'm using it in a Wordpress blog and everything works fine when the post is viewed in its actual address. But, the math parts are not rendered in Google Reader and seen as $x=\lefty*(\ b+c right)$ for instance.

The script is loaded with the statement in Wordpress header and it's not included in the RSS file. Even if it is included, Google Reader disables script tags.

Is there a proper way to fix this problem so that the subscribers can see the nicely rendered formulae in their readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine the MathJax Preview feature (see the `preRemoveClass` option at http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docs/?options/hub.html) with image generator urls, like those detailed at [LaTeX equivalent to Google Chart API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516406/latex-equivalent-to-google-chart-api)

This would require you to start encapsulating your LaTeX in `script` tags. 
For instance, the following (untested example) might work:

```
<span class="MathJax_Preview"><img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=ax^2%2Bbx%2Bc%3D0" /></span>
<script type="math/tex">ax^2+bx+c=0</script>
```

For more support you should post at:

https://math.stackexchange.com/

[MathJax help forum at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mathjax/forums/forum/948701)

Comment: I've tried the way you mention and it works out fine, thank you. But the formulae I'm adding to the blog seems to be quite complicated as opposed to simple examples of the ones given in the examples of the related apis. For instance, they contain align tags. It becomes a bit handy to write them again to work on rss feeds.